# How do you return an image without the filename or extension on the url

Tags: php, image, url-routing

So there is this webpage where this guy managed to return raw images from the server 
just by typing the id as a parameter.

http://photos.iitm.ac.in/byid.php?id=008576

even if you right click the image and open in a new tab, only the php gets opened.
does anyone know how he managed to do this?
I need this kind of functionality for profile pics

Comment: something along this line i think http://lorempixel.com/400/200/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You just have to send the data with the right Content-type. So if you want to show a gif-image just uste:

```
Header("Content-Type: image/gif");
```

and then send out the image data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

Suppose example URL is :

http://www.example.com/getImage.php?id=20

So, on getImage.php page get user image information from database and provide the image source :

Code should be like this:

```
    $userImageName="testImage.gif";         //FROM DATABASE FOR id=20, Just for example
    ob_clean();                            //CLEAN THE OUTPUT BUFFER
    header("Content-Type: image/gif");     //SET PAGE HEADER FOR IMAGE
    echo file_get_contents('imageDirectory/'.$userImageName);
    die;
```

Comment: Consider using `readfile()`. IIRC it's faster by ~20% in benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not a direct answer to the asked question, since it was already answered by other people, I think it's nonetheless worth mentioning.

You can also control the file name that appears when you try to save the picture! To do that, use following header:

```
header('Content-Disposition', 'inline;filename=my_image_title.jpg');
```

so that your script looks like this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename=my_image_title.jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($pathToImage);
//or echo $imageContent
```

Just make sure that you didn't accidentally output anything before making first call to `header()`, otherwise you might get "headers already sent" error.